# How do I get my source files to show in my Project pane after update?

Tags: intellij-idea

After an update to IntelliJ IDEA IDE, my project window is missing all the source files.  How do get all my files to show in the Project Tree pane again?

(At the moment I only see the pom.xml file, project.iml file, and External Libraries in the tree)

Comment: Assuming the files are still present on the disk, have you tried the `Reimport all maven project` button (the one with a _refresh_ blue icon) from the maven tool window?

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you so much!